# Handling "Download" window by Firefox WebDriver

Tags: python, automation, selenium, webdriver

I'm experimenting with Firefox's WebDriver and I'd like to ask if it is possible to handle  "Download" window (to accept or decline incoming download request)?

For example, simple piece of code:

```
import selenium.firefox.webdriver

dr = selenium.firefox.webdriver.WebDriver()
# Firefox is showed up.

# Let's say I'd want to download python.
dr.get('http://python.org/ftp/python/3.1.3/python-3.1.3.msi')
# Download window is showed up.
# How could I accept the download request?

# As I understand, the method below should return 
# two handles but I get only main window's handle. 
handles = dr.get_window_handles()

# Seems like WebDriver cannot "see" this popup.
```

I've experimented with this a little bit but haven't found the solution yet. I'd really appreciate any hint.

Many thanks,
   - V

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One solution to this is changing WebDriver's Firefox profile to automatically download some MIME types to a given directory.

I'm not sure how (or if) this is exposed in Python, but it's mentioned on the [Ruby bindings page](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/RubyBindings) on the Selenium wiki (under "Tweaking Firefox preferences").

Comment: is it fair to assume that the ability to tweak FF preferences is completely outside of webdriver's ablities, something written entirely in ruby? i want to do something similar for thje PHP bindings and was curious as to how it would be accomplished.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that this is the sort of thing that WebDriver was built for, but I'll take a crack at it. There is nothing built into the Firefox WebDriver to handle this specific case, but there are a few approaches you may take.

You can open FF with the profile that your WebDriver script uses and edit the preferences to always save the file instead of asking (Options > Applications > Windows Installer Package - set to "Save File"). Now, however, there's no way to tell that the file is downloading from the browser unless you get redirected to a 404 page. If not, you can check if the file exists in the Downloads directory for the same profile (Options > Main > Donwloads). If it's still in the process of downloading, the filename will be WhateverFileName.ext.part

Your other option is to use the non-visual HTMLUnit driver, navigate to the download link, click it, and the get the page source (will be the contents of the file). This works with textual files, I can't guarantee that it will work similarly for binaries, nor do I know how it will be encoded in such a case.

Best of luck

Answer (score 3):

i came across this when i was trying to download a file using capybara
and got halted by the download prompt

[SeleniumHQ : Selenium WebDriver](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp)

```
profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
profile['browser.download.dir'] = "/Downloads"
profile['browser.download.folderList'] = 2
profile['browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk'] = "audio/wav"
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox, :profile => profile
driver.navigate.to('http://www.address.com/file.wav')
```

this just downloads the file into the directory specified, no prompt :)

the other option that i came across was

[Determining file MIME types to autosave using Firefox & Watir-WebDriver](http://watirmelon.com/2011/09/07/determining-file-mime-types-to-autosave-using-firefox-watir-webdriver/)

i have tried watir before and it proved very useful