# Python Thread behavior different when code is run though IDE and command prompt

Tags: python, windows, multithreading, selenium, command-line

I had a issue while automating a web page whose solution I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17235228/which-is-the-best-way-to-interact-with-already-open-native-os-dialog-boxes-like).
In the answer by me the second code snippet which is

```
#Assume that at this point you are on the page where you need to click on a Web Element to      trigger native OS window/dialog box

def _action_on_trigger_element(_element):
    _element.click()

trigger_element = driver.find_element_by_id('ID of the Web Element which triggers the window')
th = threading.Thread(target = _action_on_trigger_element, args = [trigger_element])  #Thread is    created here to call private func to click on Save button
th.start()                          #Thread starts execution here
time.sleep(1)                       #Simple Thread Synchronization handle this case.          

#Call WindowFinder Class
win = WindowFinder()
win.find_window_wildcard(".*Save As.*") 
win.set_foreground()
path = "D:\\File.txt"            #Path of the file you want to Save 
ent = "{ENTER}"                  #Enter key stroke.
SendKeys.SendKeys(path)          #Use SendKeys to send path string to Save As dialog
SendKeys.SendKeys(ent)           #Use SendKeys to send ENTER key stroke to Save As dialog

#At this point the native OS window is interacted with and closed after passing a key stroke ENTER.
# Go forward with what ever your Automation code is doing after this point
```

When I run the code from IDE `Aptana Studio3` the code runs fine and my threads invokes the private function `_action_on_trigger_element(_element)` but when I am running the same code through command line invoking the `Python` script the thread does not invokes the function which is its target.

I checked the thread is still alive. Any explanation for this and workaround are appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Are both scenarios maybe using a different environment?

Comment: @Hyperboreus No same the only difference is how they are triggered.

Comment: What do you mean by "triggered"?

Comment: @Hyperboreus I mean the only difference is that how the scripts are executed. One from inside the IDE in which case it works fine and once through command line where the thread never invokes the private function.