# Select a file in an already open dialog box with python

Tags: python, selenium, upload, dialog

I used Selenium to execute a bunch of actions within a browser (tried both Chrome and FireFox) with a Mac.

I used a Selenium function to click a button that opens an OS level dialog box where I can select and "open" a file. I know Selenium can't interact with dialog boxes, but is there a Python function that can? `Tkinter` seems to only be able to operate within dialog boxes that it opens and not with already open boxes.

This is a version of the code and the last Selenium function that made the dialog box open is bolded:

```
import webbrowser  
from from selenium import webdriver  
element = webdriver.Chrome()  
element.get('http://www.somewebsite.com')  
uploadfunction = driver.find_element_by_id('upload_file').click()
```

I'm adamant to do this purely through Python (via command line) before resorting to another language.

Comment: Before I just randomly throw an answer at you I would strongly advise you to look at the html code that controls the button's function.  see what the html is doing exactly aside from just opening the dialog.  I ran into a similar issue a few weeks ago and found a nifty little workaround in the html.  And selenium isn't completely helpless when it comes to all dialogs.  alert = driver.switch_to_alert()

Comment: There was a whole load of things in there but the relevant part was:    <a id="upload_file" style="margin-right: 5px"><span class="c">Upload File</span><span class="r">&nbsp;</span></a>
          <span style="display:none"><input type="file" id="upload_input"/></span>
There's a chunk of javascript associated with those ids so I need to somehow make the code accept a local file (I imagine using a path here "/User/name/documents...") as the file being uploaded. I thought interacting with the dialog would be easiest.
@Amazingred

Answer (score 1):

```
import win32gui

win32gui.FindWindow(ClassName,WindowName) #should give you the control of the dialog that you want.
```

plus look at the accepted answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17235228/which-is-the-best-way-to-interact-with-already-open-native-os-dialog-boxes-like) question for a (albeit kind of messy) helper for dialogs.

If you're still stuck let me know.