# How to check if Open File dialog has been open after pressing a button in a Chrome Browser tab on Python?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, file-upload, fileopendialog

I'm trying to automate a process within the [OpenSea Create page](https://opensea.io/asset/create) after having logged in with Metamask, and so far, I have managed to develop a simple program that chooses a particular image file using a path which passes to the Open File dialog "***implicitly***", here's the code:

```
import pyautogui
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

def wait_xpath(code): #function to wait for the xpath of an element to be located
    WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, code)))


opt = Options() #the variable that will store the selenium options
opt.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress", "localhost:9222") #this allows bulk-dozer to take control of your Chrome Browser in DevTools mode.
s = Service(r'C:\Users\ResetStoreX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\chromedriver.exe') #Use the chrome driver located at the corresponding path
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=opt) #execute the chromedriver.exe with the previous conditions

nft_folder_path = r'C:\Users\ResetStoreX\Pictures\Cryptobote\Cryptobote NFTs\Crypto Cangrejos\SANDwich\Crabs'
start_number = 3


if driver.current_url == 'https://opensea.io/asset/create':
    print('all right')
    print('')
    print(driver.current_window_handle)
    print(driver.window_handles)
    print(driver.title)
    print('')
    nft_to_be_selected = nft_folder_path+"\\"+str(start_number)+".png"
    wait_xpath('//*[@id="main"]/div/div/section/div/form/div[1]/div/div[2]')
    imageUpload = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="main"]/div/div/section/div/form/div[1]/div/div[2]').click() #click on the upload image button
    print(driver.current_window_handle)
    print(driver.window_handles)
    time.sleep(2)
    pyautogui.write(nft_to_be_selected) 
    pyautogui.press('enter', presses = 2)
```

**Output:**

[image: preview0]

After checking the URL, the program clicks on the corresponding button to upload a file

[image: preview1]

**Then it waits 2 seconds** before pasting the image path into the `Name` textbox, for then pressing `Enter`

[image: preview2]

So the file ends up being correctly uploaded to this page.

The thing is, the program above works because the following conditions are met before execution:

1. The current window open is the Chrome Browser tab (instead of the Python program itself, i.e. Spyder environment in my case)
2. After clicking the button to upload a file, the `Name` textbox is selected by default, regardless the current path it opens with.

So, I'm kind of perfectionist, and I would like to know if there's a method (using Selenium or other Python module) to check if there's an `Open File dialog` open before doing the rest of the work.

I tried `print(driver.window_handles)` right after clicking that button, but Selenium did not recognize the `Open File dialog` as another Chrome Window, it just printed the tab ID of this page, so it seems to me that Selenium can't do what I want, but I'm not sure, so I would like to hear what other methods could be used in this case.

*PS: **I had to do this process this way because `send_keys()` method did not work in this page***

Comment: Not sure about other python modules, but within Selenium there's no way to get to know `Open File dialog`, it's driven from the operating system. It is not a browser handle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dialog you are trying to interact with is a native OS dialog, it's not a kind of browser handler / dialog / tab etc. So Selenium can not indicate it and can not handle it. There are several approaches to work with such OS native dialogs. I do not want to copy - paste existing solutions. You can try for example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17350440/3485434) solution. It is highly detailed and looks good.

Comment: Fair enough lol, I will give it a read. I also thank you because as a beginner sometimes I may not know the right names of the topics I need to cover, and obviously it gives me a hard time for not even knowing where to start.