# How to travel to specific file path when Chrome browser asks for a file without using Selenium(third party libraries)

Tags: python, file-browser

me here trying to find out how to achieve the next:

I am actually using **Selenium** to drive trough webpages but when I want to upload some images in any webpage the **"Open"**(**Abrir** because in spanish) file browser opens up and I want to know how to browse to the directory I want and select the file(s) that I want to upload --> For example:
I go to [imgBB URL](https://imgbb.com/) and I click the **START UPLOADING** button with Selenium but then I want to browse to an specific folder and then select some files I want, but **without using Selenium**.
[image]

Do someone knows what other libraries may I use to select the specific files that I want to upload?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Solution using pywinauto

This could be done with [pywinauto](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)

**Disclaimer**: I am not `pywinauto` guru.

```py
import pywinauto

# A handle of the opened dialog.
# "Open" is a title of the dialog window.
handle = pywinauto.findwindows.find_window(best_match="Open")
# An application that the dialog belongs to.
app = pywinauto.application.Application().connect(handle=handle)

# The dialog window itself.
open_dialog = app.window(handle=handle)

# Set the file path.
# It is not necessary to navigate to a folder, you can set an absolute file path instead.
# If you want to add multiple files you have to put each path in double quotes and separate paths with space.

# There is a little magic in this line:
# the "FileName" part depends on the text that is shown right before the input field for paths.
# In your case this should work "NombreDeArchivoEdit"
# open_dialog.NombreDeArchivoEdit.set_edit_text(r'"C:\Users\USERNAME\Pictures\img1.png" "C:\Users\USERNAME\Pictures\img1.png"')
open_dialog.FileNameEdit.set_edit_text(r'"C:\Users\USERNAME\Pictures\img1.png" "C:\Users\USERNAME\Pictures\img1.png"')

# Click the "Open" button. Same magic here.
open_dialog.Open.Click()
# Should work for you.
# open_dialog.Abrir.Click()
```

[image]

## Solution with Selenium

1. To upload files you need to find an `input` element with `type=file` that is called when the "Start uploading" button clicked

   `upload = driver.find_element(By.ID,"anywhere-upload-input")`
2. And then add a file you want to upload
   `upload.send_keys("C:\\Users\\USERNAME\\\Pictures\\IMAGE.png")`

After this, the next step window will be shown.

If you want to upload multiple files you have to combine all file paths into one string and separate them with `\n`:

`upload.send_keys("C:\\Users\\USERNAME\\Pictures\\IMAGE.png \n C:\\Users\\USERNAME\\Pictures\\IMAGE2.png")`

Here is the full code:

```py
import time

from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

service = Service("path/to/chrome/driver")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)
driver.get("https://imgbb.com/")
upload = driver.find_element(By.ID,"anywhere-upload-input")
upload.send_keys("C:\\Users\\USERNAME\\Pictures\\IMAGE1.png \n C:\\Users\\USERNAME\\Pictures\\IMAGE2.png")

time.sleep(10)

driver.quit()
```

Comment: It is useful anyways but I am looking for a script for a general solution whenever this Open file browser appears. Thanks for sharing this code, I am sure I will use this in other codes

Comment: @RedEye, I got curious about this problem and decided to get a little deeper. After some searching, think I found the solution, see the updated answer.

Comment: That's a really nice answer @elebur, I really want to give it a try maybe in the following days when I get free time in the week and I  will get back to this post to tell about the results. This surely is gonna help a bunch of beginner in this field. Thank you buddy

Comment: Well, I am back and with good news. The answer given by @elebur works like a charm it is the exact result that I wanted. I really appreciate the effort on explaining the code to get a super clear explanation of what's going on. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Today I found another useful approach from this gentlemen into making a generic solution and even showing a solution with Selenium altough is a litte bit old answer. Here is the link to the [alternative solution using native Python libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17235228/which-is-the-best-way-to-interact-with-already-open-native-os-dialog-boxes-like/17350440#17350440)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).